# Why is switching between themes breaking my child theme?

Tags: theme-development, child-theme, bug

I am working on a child theme that I am building on top of twentyseventeen. Everything was displaying as intended within my page templates. However, if I switch between my theme to another and then back, my site's pages become blank after the markup in the header.

This is what my page looks like with placeholder data. 
[image: Main page using a template page]

When I go into the Wordpress admin and click on **Appearance** this is what my page looks like.
[image]

I've double checked, and the page is still set to the correct page template in my child theme. Between these steps, I haven't done anything to the codebase, and so I believe this is something being stored in the database, in combination with some piece of code I'm neglecting.

This issue is very buggy, and has also happened now when I do a fresh install of the database and activate theme, and also when I click on Appearance, but the only way I can recreate the issue consistently is if I :
a- Set up a new db install with the theme.
b- Switch back and forth between themes.

I'm at a loss as to how to even debug this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Twenty Seventeen and WP 4.7 was the first time starter content was introduced. This allows the theme to show you sample data for how the theme can look. It is only shown on a fresh install, but it *should* only be in Customizer and only saved if you save it. Twenty Seventeen also has a setting for how the static front page is shown, as you can choose to show other pages on the front page. I'm not sure if this might be overriding your page template.